# Determine the operating system's default language in windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, operating-system

How can i detect my defult language in win 7? i means originaly installed languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your* default language may be different from *the Operating System's* default language.

There are [`GetUserDefaultLocaleName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318136.aspx) (for the current user) and [`GetSystemDefaultLocaleName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318122.aspx) (for the system).

Comment: this is for programing but i means visual how can we detect it?